# Get "id" and add in each div (name = "id")

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idPost = $('.post-outer').attr('id');
    $('.post-outer').attr('name', idPost);
});
```

When you run the JS above it only takes the first "ID" repeating in other "DIV".
What is going on:

```
<div class="post-outer" id="001" name="001">teste1</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="002" name="001">teste2</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="003" name="001">teste3</div>
```

I wanted to happen this:

```
<div class="post-outer" id="001" name="001">teste1</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="002" name="002">teste2</div>
<div class="post-outer" id="003" name="003">teste3</div>
```

Comment: The first line, `$('.post-outer').attr('id')`, gets a selector pointing to all `.post-outer` elements, but the `attr` method gets the `'id'` property of **the first element pointed to by the selector**. On the other hand, the `attr` *setter* applies to *every element* in the selector, which means all three will have a name of `"001"`. jQuery selectors are essentially wrappers around arrays of elements, and so any method which functions as a getter/setter exhibits this behavior (getters fetch from the first element, setters apply to all elements).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mpb9wfmc/2/)

```
$('.post-outer .post-footer .post-footer-line.post-footer-line-2 .post-labels a').each(function(index, el) {
     $(this).parents('.post-outer:eq(0)').attr('itemtype', $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('.post-outer').each(function() {
    $(this).attr( 'name', $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Answer (score 2):

The `.attr()` function can take a function as the argument. It calls the function repeatedly for each element (like `.each()` does), and the returned value is the new attribute value.

```
$('.post-outer').attr('name', function() {
    return this.id;
});
```

This is essentially equivalent to mevius's answer, but it doesn't call `.attr()` repeatedly.

Comment: Although my answer works, this is definitely the better answer. Thanks for sharing.